# Overlay Text on a Thumbnail Image HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to overlay some text onto a thumbnail class image. My HTML looks like so:

```
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="GreatDanesEdit.jpg" width="700" height="700">
                    <h1>Game Day</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What on Earth do I use for my CSS to get my "h1" to overlay my image? I can only seem to get it to be written underneath it. Ideally i'd like my text to be centred on the image too.

Currently my CSS looks like so, how do I centre the text over the image?

```
.thumbnail{
  position:relative;
}

.thumbnail h1{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    margin:0;
    color:#551A8B;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
    font-size: 48px;  
    font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:centre;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `relative` positioning for your `.thumbnail` element and `absolute` positioning for your `h1` element:

```css
.thumbnail{
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
}

.thumbnail img{
  max-width:100%;
}

.thumbnail h1{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  color:lightgrey;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  transform:translateY(-50%); /* doesn't work in IE9 and older I'm affraid */
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Nail(thumb).jpg">
    <h1>Game Day</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has absolutely worked out for me, thank you for solving my headache and allowing me to sleep tonight! But how to get that text to be both vertically and horizontally aligned on the image? (I'm reasonably new to this)

Comment: But it solved only part of his problem. For the full solution, check https://jsfiddle.net/pbubqt5y/1/

Comment: Agreed, this was only a semi-answer but great nonetheless! @connexo your jsfiddle link  cannot seem to word correctly in my CSS. Note that i'm using thumbnail for multiple images.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice your request to make it centered. I made an edit.

Comment: @Josh979 it is now vertically centred - just not horizontally centred.

Comment: What do you mean not horizontally centered? What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome... I mean that I see the text in the centre of the image vertically (y-axis) but not horizontally (x-axis). Currently i've just added Left:25% however this isn't the perfect solution.

Comment: Weird. I tested it to work and it's dead-center on both axises my Chrome. Like it should with `text-align:center;`. But if you can't get it to work like that, you could always try `left:50%;` and `transform:translate(-50% -50%);`

Comment: @IlpoOksanen - you are a BOSS! I've used the - left:50%; & transform:translate(-50% -50%) method and it's worked. Many many thanks, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score -2):

Try using a negative margin-top style on your h1 tag. Also align it to the center if you want it to be centered using `align="center"`.

Updated Code:

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="GreatDanesEdit.jpg" width="700" height="700">
            <h1 align="center" style="margin-top:-350px;">Game Day</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pbubqt5y/